# ajax button to show and change status of a DB field - Laravel 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to create a simple settings panel.
I want to create several buttons, which show and change status of some options and switch their value between 0 and 1.
Basically it is exacly what we use here in Stackoverflow to vote answers.

With a friendly help I was able to create this single button, which works:

View:

```
<div class="box_option flexvert invoke2">


@if(isset($userdata) && $userdata->ShowToolbar == 1)      
    <a data-remote="true" data-method="post" href="{{ route('switch.toggle_option') }}" id="experiment_update3" class="csh_07"> Activated</a>
@else
     <a data-remote="true" data-method="post" href="{{ route('switch.toggle_option') }}" id="experiment_update3" class="csh_11"> Not Activated</a>
@endif

 </div>
```

Route:

```
Route::post( '/usersettings/ajax_buttons3', array(
    'as' => 'switch.toggle_option',
    'uses' => 'UserWorkspacesController@toggle_option'
) );
```

Controller:

```
    public function toggle_option() {
```

$userdata = UserWorkspace::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();

```
if($userdata->ShowToolbar === 1)
{
    $userdata->ShowToolbar = 0;
    $response = array(
        'toggle_update' => trans('messages.un_joined')
    );
}
else
{
    $userdata->ShowToolbar = 1; // This also handles newly created UserWorkspaces
    $response = array(
        'toggle_update' => trans('messages.joined')
    );
}

$userdata->save();

        return Response::json( $response );

    }
```

JS:

```
$('a[data-remote=true]').on('ajax:beforeSend', function(xhr, settings) {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').click();
});
$('a[data-remote=true]').on('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {
    $(this).text(data.toggle_update);
});
```

Problem:

1. create **more than one** button without cloning code in the controller method or js. In Sisou's solution the controller does't know which table I want to Change - so the link must carry the information, right?
   i need c. 20 buttons in single view.
   For now the only thing I came out with is this ugly nesting IFs (sorry):

   Route::post( 'switch/{option}', array(
       'as' => 'switch.toggle_option',
       'uses' => 'UserWorkspacesController@toggle_option'
   ) );

and separate IF for each option/button to be toggled:

```
if($option = 1) {
if($userdata->ShowToolbar == 1)
{
    $userdata->ShowToolbar = 0;
 ... and so on...
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same button to change a value from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1, I suggest you let the server-side handle the appropriate value and just call a route (without any parameter) from the button. So your button would simply be

```
<a data-remote="true" data-method="post" href="{{ route('join.join_an_action') }}" id="experiment_update">
```

And you controller would check what the value currently is in the DB and then change it:

```
if($setactionstatus->Ajaxtest === 1)
{
    $setactionstatus->Ajaxtest = 0;
    $response = array(
        'interface_update' => trans('messages.un_joined')
    );
}
else
{
    $setactionstatus->Ajaxtest = 1; // This also handles newly created UserWorkspaces
    $response = array(
        'interface_update' => trans('messages.joined')
    );
}

$setactionstatus->save();
```

**As for other buttons**: you need to make the DOM crawling relative to the link:

```
$('a[data-remote=true]').on('ajax:beforeSend', function(xhr, settings) {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').click();
});
$('a[data-remote=true]').on('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {
    $(this).text(data.interface_update);
});
```

Comment: Could you mark the solution as the correct answer then? :)

Comment: I do it, but it doesn't solve the problem with multipe buttons on the same view - I updated my initial question - please check out. 
You must also edit the content to add two lines into the controller part, a a noob like me might miss out some obvious.
At the beginning this:
$userdata = UserWorkspace::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first(); 
and at the end this:
return Response::json( $response );

Comment: If you want to change different tables (meaning: different models), then there's no way around multiple `if` statements, because the model has to change as well as the attribute. For different options in the *same* model, you can set the attribute name in a `switch($option) { case 1: $attribute = 'ShowToolbar'; break; case 2: ...}` and then just have one if statement in the end that checks if it is `1` or `0`. There you would use `if($setactionstatus->attributes[$attribute] === 1) { $setactionstatus->attributes[$attribute] = 0 } else {...}`.